# Set up view in code that changes with orientation

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, view, rotation

I have set up an application and used some of the basic code from "The iPhone Developer's Cookbook" to create a simple view. The application works correctly in portrait mode, but when it is rotated, the dimensions of the boxes stay the same. Here is my code:

```
- (void)loadView {
    //Create the full application frame (minus the status bar) - 768, 1004
    CGRect fullRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]; 

    //Create the frame of the view ie fullRect-(tabBar(49)+navBar(44)) - 768, 911
    CGRect viewRect = CGRectMake(0, 64, fullRect.size.width, fullRect.size.height-93.0);

    //create the content view to the size
    contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect]; 
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Provide support for autorotation and resizing 
    contentView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    contentView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

    self.view = contentView; 
    [contentView release];

    // reset the origin point for subviews. The new origin is 0,0 
    viewRect.origin = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);

    // Add the subviews, each stepped by 32 pixels on each side 
    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(viewRect, 32.0f, 32.0f)]; 
    subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; 
    [contentView addSubview:subview]; 
    [subview release];

    subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(viewRect, 64.0f, 64.0f)]; 
    subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor]; 
    [contentView addSubview:subview]; 
    [subview release];

    subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(viewRect, 96.0f, 96.0f)]; 
    subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
    [contentView addSubview:subview]; 
    [subview release];
}
```

Is there any way to have this reload with the new dimensions when it is rotated or a better way of accommodating the orientation change?

Thanks
JP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your problem. By "boxes", do you mean the subviews?

If so, the subviews will retain their apparent dimensions when rotated because they are squares.

In any case, `viewDidLoad` is only called when a view is first initialized, usually from a nib. If you need to make changes to a view when it rotates, you need to make the changes in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and/or `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`.

To change the dimensions of any view, simply reset its frame.

Comment: Thanks a lot TechZen. These are the two methods I was looking for. Couldn't find them in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

object.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;